# Difference between List.All() and List.TrueForAll()

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a practical difference between `.All()` and `.TrueForAll()` when operating on a `List`?  I know that `.All()` is part of `IEnumerable`, so why add `.TrueForAll()`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From the [docs for `List<T>.TrueForAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w.aspx):

> Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

So it was added *before* `Enumerable.All`.

The same is true for a bunch of other `List<T>` methods which work in a similar way to their LINQ counterparts. Note that `ConvertAll` is somewhat different, in that it has the advantage of *knowing* that it's working on a `List<T>` and creating a `List<TResult>`, so it gets to preallocate whatever it needs.

Comment: I should really have thought of checking that myself.  Such an obvious answer.  Are there any performance or other differences between them?  Or do they now operate the same way?

Comment: @Bobson: That's implementation specific, but I'd be surprised to see any significant differences.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry for digging this out, but I came across this question and have seen that the actual question about differences is not properly answered.

The differences are:

1. The `IEnumerable.All()` extension method does an additional check for the extended object (in case it is null, it throws an exception).
2. `IEnumerable.All()` may not check elements in order. In theory, it would be allowed by specification to have the items to check in a different order every call. `List.TrueForAll()` specifies in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trueforall?view=net-6.0) that it will always be in the order of the list.

The second point is because `Enumerable.All` must use a `foreach` or the `MoveNext()` method to iterate over the items, while `List.TrueForAll()` internally uses a `for` loop with list indices.

However, you can also be pretty sure that the `foreach` / `MoveNext()` approach will return the elements in the order of the list entries because a lot of programs expect that and would break if this would be changed in the future.

From a performance point of view, `List.TrueForAll()` should be faster because it has one less check, and `for` on a list is cheaper than `foreach`. However, the compiler usually does a good job and optimizes here a lot, so there will probably be (almost) no measurable difference in the end.

Conclusion: `List.TrueForAll()` is the better choice *in theory*. But practically, it makes no difference.

Comment: It makes difference in game development because `All` allocates when `IEnumerator` is resolved.

Answer (score 12):

`TrueForAll` existed in .NET 2.0, before LINQ was in .NET 3.5.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 7):

`TrueForAll` appears to be specific to List, while `All` is part of LINQ.

My guess is that the former dates back to the .NET 2 days, while the latter is new in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, because this method existed before `Linq` did. `TrueForAll` on a `List` originated in `Framework 2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

`TrueForAll` is not an extension method and in the framework from version 2.