# Determine if array contains all zeroes

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I create the following array like this:

```
array<UInt16>^ temp = gcnew array<UInt16>(1000);
```

How do I determine if this entire array has been filled with zero or not.

I think I may be able to use [TrueForAll(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you not sure? Doesn't it work with your proposed function?

Comment: Well I haven't written the function, the only answer I can think of is to loop the entire array and check each element. I believe there may be a better way. In fact I should add that to the question

Comment: TrueForAll(T) also iterates through the entire array, but stopps if the condition you defined evaluates as false. You should be good with it.

Comment: @GPPK Yeap, you should add what you´ve tried and where exactly you´re stuck. In particular show where what you´ve tried doesn´t work as you expect it.

Comment: Why have you tagged C# but posted C++ code?

Comment: @DavidG because there is a lot of overlap with C++CLI in terms of what you can and can't do with .NET i believe... Although feel free to remove the C# if Im incorrect.

Comment: Well, that was unwise given that the syntax sugar you got in the answers don't help you at all.  No lambda expressions in C++/CLI.  You'll have to pick the obvious and simple approach, a for-loop has not become old-fashioned yet and is not in any way less efficient.  It is in fact much, *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work properly (here I used LINQ):

```
IEnumerable<int> values = new List<int>(); // Or use any array type instead of List.

... Add your values here ...

var allAreZero = !values.Any(v => v != 0);
```

P.S. the array class inherits `IEnumerable`.

And here is a solution with `foreach`:

```
var isAllZero = true;
foreach (var value in values)
{
    if (value != 0)
    {
        isAllZero = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

## UPDATE

The really difference between `TrueForAll`, and my `LINQ` code is: `LINQ` code uses the fluent (or maybe also query) syntax, where `TrueForAll` is just a normal function where you send the array as a parameter.

Comment: Isn't LINQ a bit slower than a native solution?

Comment: Speed was not a stated requirement.

Comment: `All` is a bit nicer for scenarios like this. `var allAreZero = values.All(v => v == 0);` No big deal, but it saves you having to negate the `Any`, meaning it's a bit more readable.

Comment: @alexanders916 Why should it? All it does it looping the list, or what do you mean by native way?

Comment: @alexanders916 I am not sure if LINQ is slower, you may test it using `StopWatch` methods. Anyway, please check my edit

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, I do not guess that `All` is better, with all it will iterate the whole items, even if it finds a non zero item. with my code it will return exits when it finds a non zero item

Comment: @HimBromBeere I meant the LINQ solution.. the way with IEnumerable is also good, but then it's easier to use TrueForAll(T), because it serves the same purpose with one Line of Code.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin - nope, it won't.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin - well if it's encountered an element that doesn't satisfy the condition, it's safe to say that not *all* elements will satisfy the condition - so it has it's answer nice and early.

Comment: @Polyfun corectness was not stated either, so does it mean it is not relevant too?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - pointless comment, don't be unnecessarily pedantic.

Comment: Buried in comment land but i've accepted this comment because it solves my problem in a C++/CLI world. It was my mistake in the original question to tag this with C# as well however I think the other answers probably solve it for that much better.

Answer (score 6):

```
var allElementsAreZero = temp.All(o => o == 0);
```

Simple as that.

It'll return when it finds one that doesn't satisfy the condition, so may not necessarily iterate through your whole collection:

**"The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined."**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will iterate through the whole array, I would use Any to return immediately when any non zero value is found

Comment: Ok that is right, I was just thinking in a different way. Then `All` is a better solution. +1

Comment: Your way was not wrong, nor is it any less efficient - it's a good answer, it's just that I've offered `All` as it's slightly more readable.

Comment: To conclude, the question makers proposed TrueForAll(T) solves his problem.

Comment: That conclusion is subject to the version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970507/1017882 So I'll leave my answer up since it'll become more and more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

initialize a counter from 0 then use for loop to interate through the array and increment the counter whenever it finds 0, and at the end compare the counter with size of array if its equal, it has all zeros

Comment: You don't need to go through the entire array, you can just exit if you find anything that isn't a zero

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [C++/CLI specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm), it has been filled with 
0s because you created it with a "new-expression" and the default value of the element type is 0.

> **24.2 CLI array creation**
>
> CLI array instances are created by new-expressions containing gcnew (§15.4.6) or …
>
> Elements of CLI arrays created by new-expressions are always initialized to their default value.